# Sum numbers in a cell that appear as a string

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Example: string in cell

```
1 1 1 1          (total should be 4)
0.5 0.5          (total should be 1)
0.125 0.125      (total should be 0.250)
0.125 0.0625 8 1 (total should be 9.1875)
```

Answer (score 1):

First use Text To Columns to get the individual numbers into individual cells.  Then use the =SUM() function across the individual numbers.

**EDIT#1**

If you need a VBA solution, then consider:

```
Public Function AddCell(s As String) As Variant
    ary = Split(Trim(s), " ")
    AddCell = 0
    For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
        AddCell = AddCell + ary(i)
    Next i
End Function
```